# nXhtml (No javascript-mode/eruby-javascript)

Tags: javascript, emacs, eruby, nxhtml

I've just installed nXhtml by downloading their zip file, extracting the archive into my home directory and adding `(load "/home/spinlock/nxhtml/autostart.el")` to my .emacs file. My problem is that when I try to edit a .js.erb file, I'm getting the error:

```
(No javascript-mode/eruby-javascript)
```

and I'm not getting the syntax highlighting that I'd expect (for instance, comments are the same color as javascript code). However, when I move the cursor inside a Ruby section of this file, that notice changes to:

```
(Ruby/eruby-javascript)
```

which I take as a good sign plus it does look like I've got the proper Ruby syntax highlighting in this part of the buffer (e.g. comments are show in red font).

I assume that I need to add a configuration file that tells emacs how to manage javascript-mode but I have no clue how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured this out but StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours because I don't have 100 reputation. So, please upvote this question (or do whatever you can do to get me reputation) if you'd like to see the answer. I'll only be at work for about 3 more hours so the answer will probably be lost if I don't memorialize it today. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so my reputation has actually fallen since I posted my last comment. I'm not sure what nerd point of etiquette I've crossed but I guess I won't be posting my answer to this question.

Comment: Write your answer here as a comment. The main thing is those who search for the question can find the answer somewhere here.

Comment: Crap. I've forgotten what I did to solve this :(